programmatically load Capital IQ's plugin
I have an excel spreadsheet where I want to pragmatically load Capital IQ plugin and perform certain macros.
I am currently using pywin32 to open excel and load the plugin. For some apparent reason the cap IQ plugin is not able to load when I perform actions such as setting the Connect property to False then True (or only setting to true).
Does anyone have any idea how I go about with loading the Cap IQ plugin with excel.
Any info would be greatly appreciated.
def wait_for_ciq_addin(excel):
retries = 20
while retries > 0:
    try:
        ciq_addin = excel.Application.COMAddIns.Item("SNL.Clients.Office.Excel.ExcelAddIn")  
        ciq_addin.Connect = False
        time.sleep(30)
        ciq_addin.Connect = True
        time.sleep(30)
        if ciq_addin.Connect:
            print("Capital IQ Add-In loaded.")
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Waiting for Capital IQ Add-In to load... {retries} retries left. Error: {str(e)}")
    time.sleep(1)
    retries -= 1
print("Capital IQ Add-In did not load in the expected time.")
return False

def run_macro(excel, macro_name):
try:
    excel.Application.Run(macro_name)
    print(f"Macro {macro_name} executed successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to run macro {macro_name}. Error: {str(e)}")

def main():
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True


workbook_path = r"PATH"
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbook_path)


if wait_for_ciq_addin(excel):
    # Run the macro
    macro_name = "Module1.Macro"
    run_macro(excel, macro_name)


workbook.Close(SaveChanges=False)
excel.Quit()

when I perform actions, such as setting the Connect property to False then True (or only setting to true). The plugin is still not connected/recognized

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
